# How to print dictionary neatly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pprint

I have a dictionary named settings.

```
>>>print settings
{u'key1': u'value1', u'key2': u'value2', u'key3': u'value3'}
```

I wanted the output like this:

```
key1: value1
key2: value2
key3: value3
```

can pprint do this? If not then which module does it? I'm using python 2.7

Comment: for key, value in settings.items():  print "{}: {}".format(key, value)